# Rails doesn't use human name for error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

in my translation file

```
activerecord:
 models:
   subject_choice: "Subject Choice"
   subject_preference: "Subject Preference"
   art_subject_choice: "Group 1 Preference"
   science_subject_choice: "Group 2 Preference"

 attributes:
  student:
    in_class: "Class"
  subject_prefernce:
    math_preference_type:
      m1: "M1"
      m2: "M2"
      m1_m2: "M1>M2"
      m2_m1: "M2>M1"
  subject:
    subject_type:
      science: "Science"
      art: "Art"
      elective: "Elective"
```

the validation is done in subject_preference model. but the error show on page is "Subject preference base Art priority cannot be same as science priority."

How can I make it display model name correctly?

UPDATE:
I just want to get rid of "Subject preference base", how can i do it? Thanks

```
errors[:base] << "Duplicated priority in science subject"
```

Comment: Typo: Fix `subject_prefernce:` => `subject_preference:`. Other than that, I have no idea what output you're expecting/why

Comment: Assuming your talking about a flash message, you can easily over ride this in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a different approach, for example

```
en:
    activerecord:
        models:
            message:
        attributes:
            message:
                content: ""
                subject: ""
```

and in my model:

```
validates :subject, :presence => { :message => I18n.t('validation.category')}
```

This approach ensures only the validation message itself is shown.

Comment: thanks for reply, but my validation method is a custom validation :(

Comment: Can you paste the custom validation?